In 1 Timothy 2:14 (KJV), what exactly is meant by the phrase "but the woman being deceived was in the transgression"?
1 Timothy 2:11-15 YLT

11 Let a woman in quietness learn in all subjection,
12 and a woman I do not suffer to teach, nor to rule a husband, but to be in quietness,
13 for Adam was first formed, then Eve,
14 and Adam was not deceived, but the woman, having been deceived, into transgression came,
15 and she shall be saved through the child-bearing, if they remain in faith, and love, and sanctification, with sobriety.

In this passage where Paul is talking about the authority of a husband vs a wife, what exactly does he mean in verse 14 where he says that because Eve was deceived, she came into the transgression? My Thayer's lexicon states that it was a case where Eve was guilty of transgressing the law even though she was ignorant to the fact that she was doing something wrong. Thayer's also seems to suggest that because Eve was deceived she overstepped her authority.

Contrary to the OP's characterization of what Thayer's Lexicon says, the Bible itself indicates that Eve was indeed aware of the Commandment.
Gen. 3

He asked the woman, “Did God really say, ‘You shall not eat from any
of the trees in the garden’?” 2 The woman answered the snake: “We may
eat of the fruit of the trees in the garden; 3 it is only about the
fruit of the tree in the middle of the garden that God said, ‘You
shall not eat it or even touch it, or else you will die.’” 4 But the snake said to the woman: “You certainly will not die! 5 God knows well that when you eat of it your eyes will be opened and you will be like gods, who know good and evil.”

Thus, the woman did know that she was not supposed to partake. The snake seduced her, and she transgressed the law.
Whether she overstepped her authority is another question. 1 Timothy indicates that

11 A woman must receive instruction silently and under complete
control. 12 I do not permit a woman to teach or to have authority over
a man. She must be quiet.

So yes, the author of 1 Timothy (some say it is not Paul because the apostle would not teach that a person is saved by child-bearing) does believe that Eve overstepped her authority. She was supposed to be taught by her husband, but she reversed the proper order of things and taught him what she learned from the serpent.

1 Timothy 1:1 tells you the author is Paul.

@alb Yes, indeed... which is why I said "some say". The NABRE introduction to 1 Timothy reviews various viewpoints, but admits "Most scholars are convinced that Paul could not have been responsible for the vocabulary and style, the concept of church organization, or the theological expressions found in the [pastoral] letters."

To our modern politically correct sensibilities, Paul argument sounds decidedly odd!  As Ellicott quotes: "*Prof. Reynolds thus comments on the argument of the Apostle:— “This may sound to our ears a far-fetched argument ... *"
However, in hermeneutics, we do not judge but simply understand what the text is saying.  (See also my answer here about 1 Tim 2:11, 12.  What is the context 1 Timothy 2?  )
Now, the fundamental mistake that interpreters make in reading this passage (so basic that it is embarrassing to those of use who have made it) is to read V12 as:

a wife I do not suffer to teach, nor to rule a husband ...

... and then jump to the unwarranted conclusion that this give license to the husband to rule over the wife - BUT the text does not say this!  Indeed, the same author Paul says this:

Eph 5:21 - Submit to one another out of reverence for Christ.

Thus, Paul, in 1 Tim 2:11-14, is saying that wives must not domineer their husbands because they should submit to their husbands - Equally, as per Eph 5:21, husbands should submit to their wives.
Thus, Paul's message in 1 Tim 2:11-14 is to remind those wives who had a tendence to bossiness and the liberation found in the Gospel of Christ, not to use this new-found freedom in Christ as an excuse to domineer their husbands.  Indeed, Paul insets a humbling fact for wives:  While both Adam and Eve sinned, it was Eve who was deceived and not Adam.
(The text of Paul's message is simply saying that Eve sinned because she was deceived, but Adam sinned because he chose to sin; and thus, was arguably a greater sin but that is another topic.)

Sin is sin whether a person is deceived or not.  But being deceived or not deceived does have ramifications as to accountability.  At the risk of getting really politically incorrect I'd say that Eve was accountable for her transgression but that Adam was doubly accountable, for hers as well as his.  He just didn't keep Eve in line and women have a tendency to go off the rails if not kept in line by hubby.  This, you might say, is where that became evident.  I could get shot or worse for saying this but I'm already mostly dead.

@moron  I smiled when upvoting your comment.  As a woman, however, the smile is wiped off my face when I remember that I truly am a daughter of Eve. 48 years of happy marriage taught me (eventually) that I was so often 'out-of-line', trying to wangle my own way. But satan's deception was to avoid approaching the man and to very slightly twist what God had said. Your bit about women needing to be kept in line by hubby comes after the fact of the man not knowing his wife had been approached. Yet he could have refused to sin himself, didn't, and so he was culpable. Men; take heed.
